# How to fix foreach loop Printing data twice in carousel bootstrap 4

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I'm looping through `$slides` which `returns` all slides in my db .

the carousel is working just fine .

i have title and second title stored in my db .

so when i loop i get the slide with the title ok. when i add another slide i get the last title and the second title of my last slide in the new one.

like this :

[screen shot](https://6.top4top.net/p_1344k3rlf1.png)

returning all slides in service provider:

```
 View::composer('main', function ($view) {
            $view->with('slides', Slide::all());
        });
```

my carousel :

```
<div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
   <ol class="carousel-indicators">
      @foreach($slides as $slider)
      <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="{{ $loop->index }}" class="{{ $loop->first ? 'active' : '' }}"></li>
      @endforeach
   </ol>
   <div class="carousel-inner">
      @foreach($slides as $s)
      <div class="carousel-item {{ $loop->first ? 'active' : '' }} carousel-image" style="background-size: cover;">
         <picture>
            <source srcset="{{asset('images/slides/main/'.$s->slideshow)}}" media="(min-width: 1400px)">
            <source srcset="{{asset('images/slides/main/'.$s->slideshow)}}" media="(min-width: 768px)">
            <source srcset="{{asset('images/slides/main/'.$s->slideshow)}}" media="(min-width: 576px)">
            <div style="background-image:url('{{asset('images/slides/main/'.$s->slideshow)}}');" class="d-block w-100 img-fluid carousel-image"></div>
         </picture>
         <div class="container">
            <div class="carousel-caption  text-center  animated fadeInUp  d-flex flex-column h-100 align-items-center justify-content-center">
               <h1 class="display-4">{{$s->title_slide}}</h1>
               <p class="lead">{{$s->title_p}}</p>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
      @endforeach
   </div>
</div>
```

what am i doing wrong?

Comment: Is the foreach loop _actually_ outputting these texts twice? It looks like that might just as well be a glitch of the slider / formatting itself … Please verify that the HTML output created is actually wrong in this regard first of all.

Comment: @misorude i just tested the loop without the slider its working fine hummm...

Comment: I dont see anything wrong in my carousel ? so any ideas?

Comment: This is mostly a css issue, nothing related to the generation of the HTML. Have you changed/removed/added a `position:relative` ?

Comment: Remove the CSS and JavaScript responsible for the slider functionality, and look at the output then, that should just be an unformatted “list” of items. Anything duplicated in there? If not, not a PHP / server-side issue to begin with.

Comment: @N69S you are right .. it turn out that the problem is from css .. i added a parallax effect to my carousel .. it was the problem thanks